# String concatenation in C-bison-flex

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a semantic analyzer using flex and bison. There, i have a matrix literal, which is something like [1,2,3;3,4;5]. Assume they are integers. I have the following rules:

In flex file:

```
int {yylval.type_id.Type=1;return tINTTYPE;}
```

In bison file:

```
char m[80]; //to keep the value of matrix literal

%union semrec
{
    struct
    {
       int Type;
       char *id;
    }type_id;
}

matrixLit : '[' row ';' rows ']'

row : value
      | value ',' row

rows : row           
       | row ';'  rows 

value : tINT      {$$.id=$1.id;}
  | tREAL      {$$.id=$1.id;}  
  | tIDENT   {$$.id=$1.id;}
```

By using these, i am trying to get the value of the matrix literal. For example, if matrix literal is [1;2;3,4;5,6], i try to get 1;2;3,4;5,6. I tried something using $$.id=$1.id and strcat(m, $1.id), strcpy(m,$1.id) etc. but whatever i do, i cannot get the values in this order. I get something like 4,2;1;3,5,6. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, always use left-recursion in bison.  Bison's parser is able to collapse the left side of the tree, creating a faster and more efficient parser.

I am going to make the assumption that it is illegal for a matrix literal to be empty.  You'll have to play around a little if this is not the behavior you desire.

```
%type <list> rows row
%%
matrixLit : '[' rows ']'

rows :  row            { $$ = create_list();  $$->add($1); }
     |  rows ';' row   { $$->add($3); }   
     ;  

row  : value           { $$ = create_list(); $$->add($1); }
     | row ',' value   { $$->add($3); }
     ;
```

You will need to add some sort of list type to your bison union.  Rows is a list of row entries, and row is a list of value entries.

Comment: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thanks, I've now been educated!

Comment: @Josh thank you, that works for the numbers but i can't handle where to put commas and semicolons?

Comment: What do you mean, where to put them?  You don't need to store them, they're throw away delimiters.

Comment: @Josh I mean, when i want to get the value of a matrixLit, for example a=[1;2,3,4;5] , i don't only want to get the numbers in order like 12345, but i also want to get the place of semicolons and cammas right, like 1;2,3,4;5

Comment: That's why you have a lists of lists ;)